# Object mapping onto subclass with JacksonXML

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am having problems with object mapping a JSON string onto a subclass in Java. I have a `Message` class which contains a `MessageType` and a `String` with the content of the message.

```
public class Message {
    protected MessageType messageType;
    protected String content;

    public MessageType getMessageType() {
        return messageType;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public void setMessageType(MessageType messageType) {
        this.messageType = messageType;
    }

    public void setContent(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }
}
```

There also is a special kind of message, this message contains an extra variable. I made this message a subclass of the `Message` class:

```
public class QuestionMessage extends Message {

    private Question question;

    public QuestionMessage() {

    }

    public Question getQuestion() {
        return question;
    }

    public void setQuestion(Question question) {
        this.question = question;
    }
}
```

Where the question class is defined as:

```
public class Question {
    private String question;
    private String answerA;
    private String answerB;
    private String answerC;
    private String correctAnswer;

    //Getters and setters down here.
}
```

Somewhere else in my code I receive a JSON string and I use Jackson's `ObjectMapper` to map this string onto the `Message` class:

```
objectMapper.readValue(jsonString, Message.class);
```

Now sometimes the JSON string is a normal message such as:

```
{"messageType":"NORMAL","content":"Content string"}
```

This JSON string get mapped successfully onto the `Message` class and it returns a `Message` object. However when my code receives special message, such as:

```
{"messageType":"NEW_QUESTION", "content":"Content String","question":{"question":"123","answerA":"123","answerB":"123","answerC":"123"}}
```

Unfortunately the my code cannot map the latter json message onto the `QuestionMessage` class.
Is it possible with JacksonXML to map onto a subclass(`QuestionMessage`) of the class(`Message.class`) you give to the objectmapper?

Or is this not possible and do I first have to search the incoming json string for a "question" node and then specifically call:

```
objectMapper.readValue(jsonString, QuestionMessage.class);
```

instead of

```
objectMapper.readValue(jsonString, Message.class);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can custom a `Deserializer` which check if there exists `question` node or not.

For exmaple:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer;

import java.io.IOException;

public class MessageDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<Message> {

    public MessageDeserializer() {
        this(null);
    }

    public MessageDeserializer(Class<?> vc) {
        super(vc);
    }

    @Override
    public Message deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt)
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        JsonNode node = jp.getCodec().readTree(jp);
        JsonNode questionNode = node.findValue("question");

        if (questionNode != null) {
            Question questionMessage = new Question();
                ...
            return questionMessage;
        } else {
            Message message = new Message();
                ...
            return message;
        }
    }
}
```

And use it:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
module.addDeserializer(Message.class, new MessageDeserializer());
mapper.registerModule(module);

Message readValue = mapper.readValue(json, Message.class);
```

Check [here](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialization) for more details.